# AngularJS beginner. ng-repeat array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS. I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="image in gallery | limitTo:'4'">
    <a href="#"><img ng-src="
    <?php echo '...' ?>{{pack.hotels.current.images[$index+1].path}}"
    alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
</div>
```

Currently I have an array of objects which have 2 properties: type and path. In the ng-repeat I iterate through all the objects. I would like to iterate only through objects in array that have the property **type==="GEN"**

While debugging, I run:

```
pack.hotels.current.images.forEach(function(item, count){ 
    if(item.type === "HAB") 
        console.log(item) 
})
```

How can I rewrite the ng-repeat statement so that it iterates only through elements that have property **type="GEN"** ? Which filter should I apply? Thank you!

Comment: what php doin in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a filter `filter: {type:'GEN'}`

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="image in gallery | filter: {type:'GEN'}| limitTo:'4'">
    <a href="#"><img ng-src="
    <?php echo '...' ?>{{pack.hotels.current.images[$index+1].path}}"
    alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use ng-repeat like this:

```
ng-repeat="image in gallery | filter:{ type: 'GEN'} | limitTo:'4'"
```